# C++ function scopes

Tags: c++, scope

I have a function "void foo()" and inside foo I call the function "void bar()"
but I keep getting the error "In function 'void foo()' error: function 'bar' was not declared in this scope".

I have done some research and can't seem to find anything that helps.
Does anyone know the issue? I'm sure it's probably simple but can't find the answer.

Comment: It's a trap!!!  Don't show the code!!!

Comment: Do you declare foo before bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared the function before you use it.

Try something like:

```
void bar(); //declaration
void foo()
{
   bar();
}
```

Alternatively, if `bar()` is declared in a different header, you can include that header instead. Or you could define `bar()` before `foo()` (unless of course bar() uses foo()).

Comment: I have, it is a whole function, hold on, I'll post the code.

Comment: Nevermind, bar was declared after foo, problem solved, and yes, I feel ashamed!

Answer (score 1):

If its in same file:

```
void bar()
{
}

void foo()
{
bar();
}
```

If its in different files:

```
#include<bar.h>  //header in which bar() is declared 

void foo()
{
bar();
}
```